# How to do I exclude a specific date range within a specific period?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-date-functions

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I need my `T-SQL` query to exclude a specific time range within a specific period.

My filtering logic stands as follows:

Extract all data which falls between `2016-07-01` and `2017-03-25` AND between `2017-07-01` and `2018-03-25` and also excluding all dates which are Saturdays and Sundays within the filtering period mentioned above.

My `T-SQL` query is as follows:

```
SELECT * from Table1
 WHERE [CreatedOn] between ...
 AND DATENAME(dw,[CreatedOn]) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

I am stuck at how to properly write the logic at `Line 2`!

Comment: Similar to `BETWEEN`, you can use `NOT BETWEEN` to filter date ranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work for you

```
SELECT * from Table1
WHERE 
(
    [CreatedOn] BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-03-25' OR
    [CreatedOn] BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-03-25'
)
AND ((DATEPART(dw, [CreatedOn]) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

**FOR KNOWLEDGE**

> The master database’s syslanguages table has a DateFirst column that
>   defines the first day of the week for a particular language. SQL
>   Server with US English as default language, SQL Server sets DATEFIRST
>   to 7 (Sunday) by default. We can reset any day as first day of the
>   week using

```
SET DATEFIRST 5
```

This will set Friday as first day of week.

@@DATEFIRST returns the current value, for the session, of SET DATEFIRST.

```
SELECT @@DATEFIRST
```

[Reference](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/22/sql-server-datefirst-and-set-datefirst-relations-and-usage/)

Comment: Thanks but how is this solution filtering the dates I want to exclude?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I changed where clause for date filter.

Comment: I think the WHERE clause should be removed after the AND.

Answer (score 2):

Combine `BETWEEN` with `AND` and `OR`.

```
SELECT 
    * 
from 
    Table1
WHERE 
    (
        [CreatedOn] BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-03-25' OR
        [CreatedOn] BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-03-25'
    )
    AND DATENAME(dw,[CreatedOn]) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
    AND CreatedOn NOT BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-02'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * from Table1
WHERE 
([CreatedOn] BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2017-03-25'
 OR
[CreatedOn] BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-03-25') 
AND DATENAME(dw,[CreatedOn]) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```